# Javascript doesn't run when loading file from local disk on Android

Tags: javascript, android, flash

While trying to develop some Android app I ran into the following problem:
I load an swf file to a `WebView`, that makes js calls. I want to catch those js calls, so I use `WebViews.addJavascriptInterface()` to do so.
Everything worked just fine when i loaded the swf file from a remote server, but when I load the same swf file form the Android file system, the javascript methods seem not to run (at least I cannot see them).

Any ideas what can cause this issue?

I don't speak js, but as far as I know in both case the js runs on client size.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of the Flash sandbox. When you run a file locally you can not run Javascript code as it does things outside the SWF. However running it from a remote server has the sandbox privileges of the domain. Check this link for more detail: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Is there any ways to modify the sandbox privilages of the file I'm loading local system?

Comment: Nope. They are enforced by the player. You can use the local-with-networking sandbox to call JS functions I believe. You will have to forfeit local file system access though.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad. Any suggestions to achive communication between Android and a locally opened swf file? :)

Comment: You can't have both networking + filesystem access in the SWF file. If you have the networking permission in the SWF and it's a local SWF, then you can talk to the Android browser.

Comment: I don't need networking permission I think, the swf file is loaded from the Android device storage to a on-app browser (WebView), and I just need to communicate to the Android system (my app) somehow.

Comment: You will need the networking permission to communicate with the browser. If you don't need to access the filesystem I think this should be fine.